# SSH authentication bypass password auth for a particular user only

Tags: unix, authentication, ssh, password-protection, ssh-keys

I am trying to build a bash script that connects to other servers to do some basic monitoring like checking disk space and have this information emailed. I still need all these servers require a password for general entry/access by users but for this particular monitoring script I don't want to be asked a password (general ssh key only)

How do I can configure a particular user (lets call it `monitor`) connect to a server with the following command but not ask for the password (as it will be for a cron so needs to be automated)

// ssh to web1 server and get diskspace

`cmd=$(ssh web1 df -h | grep -E "xvda1|xvde1" | awk '{print $5};' | sort -r | head -1)`

lets say the servers have 3 users 'monitor', 'bob' & 'paul'

When it hits this part of the script the `ssh web1` forces me to enter a password - is it possible to setup a particular user (in this case the `monitor` user) to be able authenticate & login using `ssh some-ip` without asking for the password but still have it ask for the passwords when either `bob` or `paul` try to login?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is quite simple: just create an SSH key for *monitor* user only (`ssh-keygen`), and then copy it's private key to other servers (`ssh-copy-id SERVER-IP-OR-NAME`).

Just check `PubkeyAuthentication` is enabled on the server, but it is enabled by default...

This way user *monitor* will be logged without asking password, and other users will be required of their password.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you have to copy your `RSA` key to the server and enable the `RSA` authentication.

You can generate the key using `ssh-keygen` and following the instructions, then copy it to the server using `ssh-copy-id` and enabling the `PubkeyAuthentication` on the server. Be sure to restart the `sshd.service`!

Resource: [openSSH docs](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id)